# How to make qt window can't change size without setFixedSize?

Tags: qt

I need setup a window with QVBoxLayout,and I don't know it's real size.So when I tried `setFixedSize(this->size())` after all widgets been added,it dosen't work.

**Is there a `windowFlag` which can make Qt window not resizable?**

Comment: Have you tried `layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);`?

Answer (score 0):

`layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)`.That's work,thanks@Ngoc Minh Nguyen